# How to I align the right container with the left container in terms of top margin?

Tags: html, css, alignment

I have the following code:

html:

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="left">
        <div class="panel">My Panel</div>
    </div>
    <div class="right"></div>
</div>
```

css:

```
.container {
    background-color: #000;
    margin: 130px auto;
    min-height: 320px;
    width: 940px;
    overflow: auto;
    padding: 0px 10px;
}
.left {
    width: 600px;
    margin-right: 20px;
}
.right {
    width: 320px;
    height: 300px; 
    background-color: #999;
    float: right;
}
.panel {
    background-color: red;
}
```

The `.right` div doesn't align with the `.left` div in terms of margin top.  The `.right` div shows a bit below the `.left` div.  how can i align it so that the `.right` div is aligned with the `.left` div *only* in terms of the margin top?

Comment: Add `float:left` to your left div?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Due to how floats work, the `.right` div is pushed by the `.panel` div that `.left` contains because it is not floated.

One simple solution is to move the `.right` div *before* `.left` in the HTML: http://jsfiddle.net/sRVDW/

Another is to `float: left` the `.left` div: http://jsfiddle.net/sRVDW/1/

Answer (score 1):

```
.left {
    float: left; /* ADD THIS */
    width: 600px;
    margin-right: 20px;
}
```

Just add `float: left` to your left div.